motion.div isn't following the target in useTransform
code:
export const AboutSection = () => {
  const container = useRef(null);
  const { scrollYProgress } = useScroll({
    target: container,
  });
  const y = useTransform(scrollYProgress, [0, 1], ["0%", "100%"]);
  return (
    <div ref={container} style={{ height: "200vh", background: "black" }}>
      <motion.div style={{ position: "fixed", top: 0 }}>
        <motion.div
          style={{
            y,
            width: 20,
            height: 20,
            background: "gray",
          }}
        ></motion.div>
      </motion.div>
    </div>
  );
};

i forgot how but i used to make when the target (ref:container) scrollYProgress value be 1
the motion.div will be at the bottom but in ["0%", "100%"] the 100% here is going with the motion.div height but i want the 100% to be the target container height (200vh)
